# Perl: Split file based on blank lines for processing

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have Data file that has a regular pattern from which I need to extract information. 
Each section is seprated by a blank line. 
Hence I was wondering if I could split the file for processing based in blank lines.

To better explain my problem, let me share the sample structure:

```
 Block: A1
 -----------------------------------
 Height:                       24.00
 Width:                         0.79
 Depth:                         0.04
 -----------------------------------

 Block: A2
 -----------------------------------
 Height:                       20.00
 Width:                         1.00
 Depth:                         0.54
 -----------------------------------

 Block: B1
 -----------------------------------
 Height:                        4.00
 Width:                         4.50
 Depth:                         0.87
 -----------------------------------
```

In this Database I need to simplify the report by making multiple columns. 
The algorithm that I am trying to achieve is that if I can split the file into smaller sections based on blank lines, I could read the database into a two-dimenstional array and finally dump the data into a format of my choice. 
Hence, the first requirement is to undertand in case I can split the file based on blank lines for further processing.

My expected final result is

```
              A1      A2     B1
 Height:     24.00  20.00   4.00
 Width:       1.00   4.00   4.50
 Depth:       0.04   0.54   0.87
```

Any suggestions/clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to split the file for processing based in blank lines using "paragraph mode".

```
local $/ = "";
while (my $block = <>) {
   ...
}
```

But it's easier not to.

```
my $block;
my $data;
while (<>) {
   if (/^Block:\s*(\S+)/) {
      $block = $1;
   }
   elsif (/^(\S+):\s*(\S+)/) {
      $data{$1}{$block} = $2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(<>)
{
push @B,$1 if(/Block:\s*(\S*)/);
push @H,$1 if(/Height:\s*(\S*)/);
push @W,$1 if(/Width:\s*(\S*)/);
push @D,$1 if(/Depth:\s*(\S*)/);
}

print "\t\t @B \n";
print "Height @H \n";
print "Width @W \n";
print "Depth @D \n";
```

Tested [Here](http://ideone.com/DDmDTL)